# Excel Data Validation (Text Length)

Tags: excel, vba, validation, error-handling

This will probably have to be something that is done in VBA, which is fine.

Some background information: I am wanting to use the text length option in Excel's Data validation. I am needing to limit to 60 characters or less. This is the easy part, however.

My question is, if a user has exceeded this 60-character threshold, I do not want my error alert to remain static and give a generic response saying "you must keep below 60 characters..." I want it to actually *count* the number of characters the user attempted to place in the cell, then on the Error Alert popup I would like it to be more specific, such as: `You have exceeded the 60-character limit by ## characters. Please shorten the input and try again.` Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: The [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) (or [Workbook_SheetChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196611.aspx)) event macro can replace data validation and add much more functionality.

Comment: Please don't type your question title in all CAPS. It's not polite to shout, and it won't get you answers any more quickly. It also makes your title more difficult to read, and it's rather rude and annoying. Proper cased text is much easier to read. You don't see any other question titles in ALL CAPS on the main page, do you?

Comment: I rate you actually write a .VSTO add in in visual studio using VB.NET, purely because it's just a wee bit easier in my opinion, and you can do more, for instance, you can make use of the event handlers on controls, so you could access the TextChanged event of a textbox to display an error message or whatever, but only for a second or so, and then continue or don't. In VBA, it is, in my opinion, somewhat limited, for instance, no event handlers (to my knowledge) and like... no textbox.contains method... But VB.NET, does however. 

Try it out :) It's not too hard... 

Will give it a whirl.

Comment: No problem. Can you keep it in mind for future posts? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote something similar to the code provided by [K Davis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5781745/k-davis) in another answer. Beyond coding style, here are major functional differences.

<sup>•  handles multiple target columns

        •  adds address to message

        •  selects the rogue cell after notification

        •  loops backwards so that in the event of multiple rogue inputs, the user ends up at the first

        •  declaration and assignment of variables are reserved to when they are actually required

        •  critical stop message box</sup>

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Union(Columns("B"), Columns("D"))) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim mssg As String, iLimit As Long, a As Long, t As Long, trgt As Range
        iLimit = 60
        Set trgt = Intersect(Target, Union(Columns("B"), Columns("D")))
        'loop backwards through multiples so we end up at the first rogue entry
        For a = trgt.Areas.Count To 1 Step -1
            For t = trgt.Areas(a).Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
                If Len(trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).Value2) > iLimit Then
                    mssg = "You have exceeded the  " & iLimit & "-character limit by " & _
                            Len(trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).Value2) - iLimit & " characters in " & _
                            trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).Address(0, 0) & ". Please shorten the input and try again."
                    MsgBox mssg, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Bad Input"
                    trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).ClearContents: trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).Select
                End If
            Next t
        Next a
        Set trgt = Nothing
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

[image: text_length_validation]

You might want to split the sentences with one or two `vbLF`. To my eye, it makes the alert message more effective; particularly so with the cell address added.

I had thought about putting all of the rogue input cell addresses into a single message but that would preclude the specific overdrawn character count.

---

<sub>Sample text courtesy of [Lorem Ipsum Generator](http://lipsum.com/)</sub>

Comment: After the procedure is finished the indications about the cells to be retype and the exceeded number of characters per cell is gone. Suggestion 1) Cell comments could be used to mark the cells that needs retyping and the indicated the exceeded characters. 2)A combination of a final box message to indicate that some cells needs retyping while the comments in the cells flag the cells and indicated the exceeded chars.

Comment: Cont... Suggestion 1 can be achieved by replacing these lines: `MsgBox mssg, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Bad Input"` and `trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).ClearContents: trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).Select` with these 
`With trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t)` 
`.AddComment` 
`.Comment.Text Text:=mssg` 
`.Comment.Visible = True` 
`.ClearContents` 
`.Select` 
`End With` 
`Else` 
`trgt.Areas(a).Cells(t).ClearComments` 
`End If`

Comment: Removing the [Range.ClearContents method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223828%28v=office.11%29.aspx) should take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a suggestion made by Jeepeed, I performed an internet search and stumbled upon [this site](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010003_Setting_a_Length_Limit_on_Cells.html). I have modified this person's code a bit to accomplish what I needed in my original question, and would like to share it in the event anyone else comes across my same issue.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iChars As Integer
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'Change these as desired
    iChars = 60
    Set rng = Me.Range("B:B")

    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In Intersect(Target, rng)
            If Len(rCell.value) > iChars Then
                MsgBox "You have exceeded the 60-character" & _
                " limit by " & Len(rCell.value) - iChars & _
                " characters." & vbCrLf & "Please shorten" & _
                " your input and try again.", vbRetryCancel
            End If
        Next
    End If

ExitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you interested in supplements to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be better with an Excel formula next to the cell:

```
= IF( LEN( B2 ) > 60, "You have exceeded the 60-character limit by " 
  & ( LEN( B2 ) - 60 ) & " characters. Please shorten your input and try again.", "" )
```